# Why won't it properly calculate an average of members?

Tags: c, average

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int group, regular_group, regular_members, shutdown, special_group,
    special_members;
float average_special, average_regular;
main()
{
  do
  {
    printf("How many members are in the group?\n");
    scanf("%d", &group);

    if (group >= 15)
    {
      regular_group = regular_group + 1;
      regular_members = regular_members + group;
      printf("Do you want to add another group? yes = 1, no = 0 \n");
      scanf("%d", &shutdown);
    }

    else
    {
      special_group = special_group + 1;
      special_members = special_members + group;
      printf("Do you want to add another group? yes = 1, no = 0 \n");
      scanf("%d", &shutdown);
    }
  }

  while (shutdown == 1);

  average_regular = regular_members / regular_group;
  average_special = special_members / special_group;

  printf("\nTotal regular members:\n%d\n", regular_members);
  printf("\nTotal special members:\n%d\n", special_members);

  printf("\nAverage regular members in a group:\n%f\n", average_regular);
  printf("\nAverage special members in a group:\n%f\n", average_special);
  fflush(stdin);
  getchar();

}
```

If a group is larger than 15 its automatically a regular group but if its less than its a special group. I need the total amount of memebrs of each catergory. 
The total amount of members is working fine. But I also need the average size of a group of both catergories.  But the average is always 0,000000. But I cant find the error.. Please help me

Thank you very much !

Comment: ah thats a translating mistake. I forgot to translate that from dutch>english. In my original code it is the same

Comment: Working here, besides the fact that it crashes if not least one time one entered a value >15 and one time a value <15. For example `1<enter>1<enter>16<enter>0` outputs `16.00000<cr/lf>1.00000<cr/lf>`.

Comment: @alk Just a division by zero check is required to avoid that.

Comment: Btw: It's `int main(void)`!

Comment: To help debug, change your format from `%f` to `%e` to see if `average_regular` is really 0.000000.

Comment: Unclear as what you gain with `fflush(stdin)`.  Maybe you want `fflush(stdout)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because

1. You are dividing two integers `regular_members/regular_group` which gives an integer after division. If numerator will become less than denominator then you will get `0` as a result.
2. You are not initializing the variables `regular_group`, `regular_members`, `special_group`, `special_members`, `average_special`and `average_regular`.

Instead of using

```
average_regular = regular_members/regular_group;
average_special = special_members/special_group;
```

try this

```
average_regular = (float)regular_members/regular_group;
average_special = (float)special_members/special_group;
```

Also remove `fflush(stdin)`. It will invoke undefined behavior.
Declare your variables

```
int group, regular_group, regular_members, shutdown, special_group,
special_members;
float average_special, average_regular;
```

inside `main` function

```
main()
{
     int group, regular_group, regular_members, shutdown, special_group, special_members;
     float average_special, average_regular;
     ....
     ....
}
```

and do not forget to **initialize the variables**: `regular_group`, `regular_members`, `special_group`, `special_members`, `average_special`, `average_regular` to `0`.

---

Here is your working code (after some modifications)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int group, regular_group = 0, regular_members = 0, shutdown, special_group = 0,
    special_members = 0;
    float average_special = 0, average_regular = 0;

  do
  {
        printf("How many members are in the group?\n");
        scanf("%d", &group);

        if (group >= 15)
        {
            regular_group = regular_group + 1;
            regular_members = regular_members + group;
            printf("Do you want to add another group? yes = 1, no = 0 \n");
            scanf("%d", &shutdown);
        }

        else
        {
            special_group = special_group + 1;
            special_members = special_members + group;
            printf("Do you want to add another group? yes = 1, no = 0 \n");
            scanf("%d", &shutdown);
       }
  } while (shutdown != 0);

if(regular_group != 0)              //to stop division by zero
    average_regular = (float)regular_members / regular_group;
if(special_group != 0)              //to stop division by zero  
    average_special = (float)special_members / special_group;

printf("\nTotal regular members:\n%d\n", regular_members);
printf("\nTotal special members:\n%d\n", special_members);

printf("\nAverage regular members in a group:\n%f\n", average_regular);
printf("\nAverage special members in a group:\n%f\n", average_special);

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are doing divisions between integers.
Also if the result variable is float this is not sufficient to have the operation will be executed as you expect.

You need to use type casts like this:

```
average_regular = (float)regular_members/(float)regular_group;
average_special = (float)special_members/(float)special_group;
```

Actually it could be sufficient to put the cast only on one of the two members of each operations to have the operation compiled as float division:

```
average_regular = (float)regular_members/regular_group;
average_special = (float)special_members/special_group;
```

Comment: No I still get the 0.00000 as answer

Comment: As per C99, if you're doing algebraic operations amongst multiple numbers, all numbers involved are up-cast to the necessary type to accommodate the operation taking place. The first of the two operations is the better of the two, because the compiler will implicitly cast the denominator in the second case anyways. At least in the first case, your intent is shown explicitly. As for the poster, can you provide us the output of a sample run? Print out all the elements as you go, etc?

Comment: Sadly, I've found "normal" expectations can yield varied results in different build environments. I find having to cast things often using gcc on Windows for embedded targets. Most recent lesson: finding & proving `abs()` doesn't work in my world.

Answer (score 1):

Division `regular_members/regular_group` yields a integer result so any fraction becomes 0.

Cast one of the variables to float and the division will result in a float.

```
average_regular = regular_members/(float)regular_group;
```

And similar for the other version `average_special`.

-Also your main is declared incorrectly, is should be at least `int main( void )`

-And `fflush(stdin);` is not a correct way to clear the buffer. It may result in undefined behavior.

-You are might invoke division by zero here `average_regular = regular_members / regular_group;`

Comment: @svenweer You probably did something wrong, after the fix the code produced a float result.

Answer (score 1):

there no problem with your code . 
Only problem is Global virable are initialised to 0 so when you do not have any special or regular group then

```
regular_group or special_group value will be 0.
```

and any no divided by 0 give floating point exception . I hope you got the point .

```
main() must return int .
```

rest there is no problem .